# How to interpret Chrome's "timestamp" property in debug mode

Tags: node.js, performance, google-chrome

I have a nodeJS script that generates HAR files by connecting to Chrome (in debug mode)

What I'm trying to figure out is what the "timestamp" property in "Network.requestWillBeSent" object stands for. This is the sample "message.params" object:

```
{
requestId: '6868.1321',
frameId: '6868.2',
...
timestamp: 70683.66357,
wallTime: 1449020270.68483
}
```

I initially thought that timestamp is in milliseconds or seconds. So I have tried doing addition/subtraction on wallTime. All the results that I got don't make much sense. Can anybody help?

Let me know if you need additional info on this. Thanks!

UPDATE:
I think I got it figured out. It seems wallTime is in *seconds*, while timestamp is in *microseconds*. I'll go with this for now. I'll provide another update in case something new turns up.